# Angular material's progress circular directive is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to show a progressive circular symbol using angular-material's directive "md-progress-circular"(https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressCircular). I have included both angular-material.js as well as angular-material.css file. But still I am not able to see any circular symbol on the view.

The code that I have written in html file is -

```
<md-progress-circular md-mode="determinate" value="{{host.volumePercentage}}" md-diameter="25"></md-progress-circular>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! This is straight from their documentation. You got to make sure the determinateValue is appropriately incremented based on whatever event you are waiting for.

```js
var demoApp = angular.module('demo', ['ngMaterial']);
demoApp.controller('demoController', function($interval, $scope) {

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="demoController">
    <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I just want to display a particular percentage, not in a progressive manner. Hence I think js code is not needed. And also I have added all the angularJS libraries, still its not working.

Comment: So you want an 'interdeterminate' one? That will show the spinner until you decide to hide it.

Comment: No not an interdeterminate one. I want a determinate one only but it should display at glance for ex. 74%, not in an incremental manner. Hence for it no JS code will be needed.

Comment: It worked. I forget to add ngMaterial as a dependency to my module. Thanks